# The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm struggling with the below query, using Entity Framework (v4).

I already have an `IQueryable<T>` object called `_myTable`. I'm now trying to add some filtering.

MyTable (as a table) is part of relationship, and joins to another table called MyCompany, which in turns is a one to many to another tabled called MyPeople. Within MyPeople is a date column, and I'm trying to filter between a Min() and Max() (person started/left company).

My code is

```
this._myTable = from v in this._myTable
             group v by v.MyCompany.MyPeople into grouped
             where EntityFunctions.DiffDays(grouped.Min(s => s.DateTime), grouped.Max(s => s.DateTime)) > 0
             select grouped.FirstOrDefault();
```

The program runs but when I inspect the results I see an exception has been thrown.

> "The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider."

I've tried to understand the answer but I can't - I can read what it says, I understand that the selector type is not comparable, but I don't understand how I can fix it!

Comment: is this MyCompany.MyPeople defined as complex type?

Comment: Please add database models to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `v.MyCompany.MyPeople` is probably a reference to another table (`MyPeople`). Try changing it to `v.MyCompany.MyPeople.Id` (or whatever the name of the primary key of `MyPeople` is.)